# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, customvalidator

I make this component with custom validate and declare variable in top of component and assigning value to , but when i use this variable inside custom validation it return this error if change value in form "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')"
in custom valide extention file I have to declare and assign value to variable inside '
so I want to know the  reason of that
is custom validate fun not observe so it excute before other fun?,
but why variable value donot existing and assigning to undefiend,
and how i use file size in validate file size?
in all conditions this is code of component

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PagedResult } from 'src/app/core/models/pagedResult.model';
import { AlertService } from 'src/app/core/services/alert.service';
import { FakeDataService } from 'src/app/core/services/fake-data.service';
import { Employee } from '../../models/employee.model';
import { PenaltyReason } from '../../models/penalty-reason.model';
import { PenaltyType } from '../../models/penalty-type.model';
import { Penalty } from '../../models/penalty.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-penalties',
  templateUrl: './penalties.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./penalties.component.css']
})
export class PenaltiesComponent implements OnInit {

  penalties: PagedResult<Penalty>;
  page = 1;
  formTitle = "اضافة عقوبة";
  penaltyTypes: PenaltyType[];
  penaltyReasons: PenaltyReason[];
  employees: Employee[];
  selectedPenaltyIndex: number;
  penaltyForm: FormGroup;
  file: FormControl;

  constructor(private fakeData: FakeDataService, private alert: AlertService) { }

  loadData() {
    this.fakeData.getDataFor('Penalties', this.page).then(result => {
      this.penalties = result as PagedResult<Penalty>;
    });
  }

  loadRequiredData() {
    //load penalty Types
    this.fakeData.getAllDataFor('PenaltyTypes').then(result => {
      this.penaltyTypes = result as PenaltyType[];
    });

    // Loading penalty Reasons
    this.fakeData.getAllDataFor('penaltyReasons').then(result => {
      this.penaltyReasons = result as PenaltyReason[];
    });

    // Loading Employees list
    this.fakeData.getAllDataFor('Employees').then(result => {
      this.employees = result as Employee[];
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resetForm();
    this.loadData();
    this.loadRequiredData();
  }

  paginateData(page: number) {
    this.page = page;
    this.loadData();
  }

  showEditForm(id: number, index: number) {
    var penalty2Edit = this.penalties?.data?.find(p => p.Id == id) as Penalty;
    this.penaltyForm?.setValue({ ...penalty2Edit });
    this.selectedPenaltyIndex = index;
  }

  delete(id: number) {
    var itemIndex = this.penalties.data.findIndex(c => c.Id == id);
    this.penalties.data.splice(itemIndex, 1);

    this.alert.showSuccess('تم مسح العنصر بنجاح');
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.file = new FormControl(null);
    this.penaltyForm = new FormGroup({
      Id: new FormControl(0),
      FingerPrintId: new FormControl(0),
      EmpId: new FormControl(0),
      EmpName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      Date: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      PenalityTypeId: new FormControl(0),
      PenalityTypeText: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      DeductionDaysCount: new FormControl(0, Validators.required),
      ReasonTypeId: new FormControl(0, Validators.required),
      DisciplineNotes: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      ImageURL: new FormControl('', [this.ValidateExtentionFile, this.validateFileSize])
    });
    this.loadRequiredData();
  }

  addPenalty() {
    this.penaltyForm.get('Id')?.setValue(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));

    this.penalties.data.unshift(this.penaltyForm.value);
    this.resetForm();
    this.alert.showSuccess("تم إضافةالعقوبة بنجاح");
  }

  updatePenalty() {
    this.penalties.data.splice(this.selectedPenaltyIndex, 1, this.penaltyForm.value);
    this.alert.showSuccess('تم تعديل العنصر بنجاح');
  }

  // deal with file
  onFileSelected(event: any) {
    this.file.setValue(event.target.files[0]);
    console.log(this.file);
  }

  ValidateExtentionFile(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {

    if (!control.value)
      return null;

    let allowedEXT = ['jpg', 'png', 'pdf', 'jpeg'];
    var fileExt = control.value?.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    if (allowedEXT.includes(fileExt))
      return null;


    return { valideFileEXT: true };
  }

  validateFileSize(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {

    let maxSize = 1;

    if (!control.value || !this.file)
      return null;

    const fileSize = (this.file.value.size / 1024 / 1024); // convert to MB


    if (fileSize > maxSize) {
      return { 'validateFileSize': true };
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: this is all error :-ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')
    at validateFileSize (penalties.component.ts:133:33)
    at forms.mjs:821:40
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at executeValidators (forms.mjs:821:23)
    at FormControl._composedValidatorFn (forms.mjs:852:28)
    at FormControl._runValidator (forms.mjs:2262:38)
    at FormControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.mjs:2239:32)
    at FormControl.setValue (forms.mjs:3703:14)
    at updateControl (forms.mjs:3198:13)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (forms.mjs:3183:13)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

in the component file:

```
 handleFileInput(files: any) {
    this.fileNameDetail = undefined;
    const image = files.files.item(0);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      this.imageUrl = reader.result;
    }, false);
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  }
```

in the template file:

```
 <button (click)="filePicker.click()" class="file-picker-opener">انتخاب فایل</button>
  <input type="file"
         class="form-control"
         #filePicker
         accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg"
         id="file"
         (change)="handleFileInput($event.target);"
  />
```

Comment: still give me the same error